# Sunscreen vs sunblock

Tags: meaning

These two words have very similar definitions on Google. One protects against UVA and one protects against UVB rays. The question is, at what times should I use one word, and the other? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: I would hope that ***both*** sunscreen and sunblock protect against both UVA and UVB rays. Because if a product doesn't protect against both kinds of UV, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: The difference is that sunblock is what Larry David uses when he goes golfing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For many speakers, *sunscreen* and *sunblock* are completely interchangeable.

Here are the definitions according to Oxford Dictionaries:

> [***Sunblock***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sunblock)
>
> A cream or lotion for protecting the skin from the sun and preventing sunburn.
>
> [***Sunscreen***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sunscreen?q=sun%20screen)
>
> A cream or lotion rubbed onto the skin to protect it from the sun.

Other dictionaries also give synonymous definitions.

Any definitions which attempt to draw a technical distinction, say between protection from UVA rays and protection from UVB rays, is likely going beyond common usage. This is not a distinction most laypeople draw, since most laypeople are not in possession of the concepts UVA and UVB rays.

That said, some laypeople still draw a distinction between the two substances, with *sunscreen* being a weaker, less opaque versions of *sunblock*. These connotations can be seen in the respective root words ***screen*** and ***block***. The idea is that sunscreen merely *screens* you from the sun, while sunblock completely *blocks* it out.

For this reason, the Food and Drug Administration (FDA) seems to have issued technical definitions, as well as regulations regarding the use of the terms on products. Here is a relevant passage from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunscreen#Sunblock):

> The use of the word "sunblock" in the marketing of sunscreens is controversial. Since 2013, the FDA has banned such use because it can lead consumers to overestimate the effectiveness of products so labeled. Nonetheless, many consumers use the words "sunblock" and "sunscreen" synonymously.

This passage seems to confirm that many speakers use the terms synonymously, although it also acknowledges the existence of connotations of strength.

*Sunscreen* seems to be about 6 times more frequent than *sunblock*, as evinced by [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sunblock%2Csunscreen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csunblock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csunscreen%3B%2Cc0) ngram.

In short, the answer to your question is the following: Many speakers use *sunscreen* and *sunblock* interchangeably, but many others use them with different connotations of strength.

Comment: And then there’s _sun cream_ and _sun lotion_, which presumably are imagined to be even less effective and visible…